# Visio automatically changes the font of org chart boxes for me

Tags: visio

I want to make my Visio boxes have a specific font and size that is not the default. Whenever I try and change, let's say to "XYZ", it will automatically change the font back to the default and add a space below the XYZ which causes the XYZ to move up on the box.

So in conclusion, the font and size will automatically change back to default, and it will for some reason also add a space below the text string.

Comment: Have you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click the stencil that contains the shape(s) you want to edit, click Save As and give the stencil a useful name.
2. Now the stencil is editable,Right-click the shape whose defaults you want to change, select Edit master → Edit Master Shape and edit away.
3. When you're done, close the window (not Visio) and make sure to save the changes

Check this link too :)

[How do I change the default font size in visio](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_visio-mso_winother/how-do-i-change-the-default-font-size-in-visio/65a1d07a-861c-4370-ab47-bb21d59efaae)